# rvm gempath issue (Could not find RubyGem >=0 error)

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed ruby using rvm (no gemsets) and am now trying to install passenger. However I get the error that the passenger gem (already installed) wasn't found. This appears off as the GEM_PATH environment variable is properly set.

The main problem I see is that 'gempath' in configuration is not set to anything. Does anyone know how to set this? Am I correct in assuming this is the problem?

**NOTE:** I have already looked at [Yehuda Katz's post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/24/a-tale-of-abort-traps-or-always-question-your-assumptions/) but rehashing doesnt seem to help (+ I wasnt using bundle)

```
RubyGems Environment:
    - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
    - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
    - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home4/onezerh4/ruby/gems
    - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home4/onezerh4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
    - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home4/onezerh4/ruby/gems/bin
    - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x86_64-linux
    - GEM PATHS:
        - /home4/onezerh4/ruby/gems
    - GEM CONFIGURATION:
        - :update_sources => true
        - :verbose => true
        - :benchmark => false
        - :backtrace => false
        - :bulk_threshold => 1000
        - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
        - "gemhome" => "/home4/onezerh4/ruby/gems"
        - "gempath" => []
        - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
    - REMOTE SOURCES:
        - http://rubygems.org/
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you specify some settings in `~/.gemrc`:

```
    - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
    - "gemhome" => "/home4/onezerh4/ruby/gems"
    - "gempath" => []
    - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
```

you need to remove at least the `gemhome` and `gempath` entries from `~/.gemrc`

also note that you do not need to add `--remote` to `gem`